# cosine similarity on large sparse matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, memory, matrix, cosine-similarity

The code below causes my system to run out of memory before it completes.

Can you suggest a more efficient means of computing the cosine similarity on a large matrix, such as the one below?

I would like to have the cosine similarity computed for each of the 65000 rows in my original matrix (`mat`) relative to all of the others so that the result is a 65000 x 65000 matrix where each element is the cosine similarity between two rows in the original matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

mat = np.random.rand(65000, 10)

sparse_mat = sparse.csr_matrix(mat)

similarities = cosine_similarity(sparse_mat)
```

After running that last line I always run out of memory and the program either freezes or crashes with a MemoryError. This occurs whether I run on my 8 gb local RAM or on a 64 gb EC2 instance.

Comment: `sparse` has its own `random` function, that can create a matrix with lots of zeros.

Answer (score 15):

Same problem here. I've got a big, non-sparse matrix. It fits in memory just fine, but `cosine_similarity` crashes for whatever unknown reason, probably because they copy the matrix one time too many somewhere. So I made it compare small batches of rows "on the left" instead of the entire matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def cosine_similarity_n_space(m1, m2, batch_size=100):
    assert m1.shape[1] == m2.shape[1]
    ret = np.ndarray((m1.shape[0], m2.shape[0]))
    for row_i in range(0, int(m1.shape[0] / batch_size) + 1):
        start = row_i * batch_size
        end = min([(row_i + 1) * batch_size, m1.shape[0]])
        if end <= start:
            break # cause I'm too lazy to elegantly handle edge cases
        rows = m1[start: end]
        sim = cosine_similarity(rows, m2) # rows is O(1) size
        ret[start: end] = sim
    return ret
```

No crashes for me; YMMV. Try different batch sizes to make it faster. I used to only compare 1 row at a time, and it took about 30X as long on my machine.

Stupid yet effective sanity check:

```
import random
while True:
    m = np.random.rand(random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))
    n = np.random.rand(random.randint(1, 100), m.shape[1])
    assert np.allclose(cosine_similarity(m, n), cosine_similarity_n_space(m, n))
```

Comment: This is a solution that worked very well for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're running out of memory because you're trying to store a 65000x65000 matrix. Note that the matrix you're constructing is **not** sparse at all. [`np.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) generates a random number between 0 and 1. So there aren't enough zeros for `csr_matrix` to actually compress your data. In fact, there are [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) no zeros at all.

If you look closely at your `MemoryError` traceback, you can see that [`cosine_similarity`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) tries to use the sparse dot product if possible:

```
MemoryError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    887         Y_normalized = normalize(Y, copy=True)
    888 
--> 889     K = safe_sparse_dot(X_normalized, Y_normalized.T, dense_output=dense_output)
    890 
    891     return K
```

So the problem isn't with `cosine_similarity`, it's with your matrix. Try initializing an actual sparse matrix (with 1% sparsity, for example) like this:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((65000, 10))
>>> i = np.random.rand(a.size)
>>> a.flat[i < 0.01] = 1        # Select 1% of indices and set to 1
>>> a = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
```

Then, on a machine with 32GB RAM (8GB RAM was not enough for me), the following runs with no memory error:

```
>>> b = cosine_similarity(a)
>>> b
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: my mistake - i didn't intend for it to be a sparse matrix. i intended to take my original matrix (mat) and use that to compute a 65000 x 65000 matrix where each element represents the cosine similarity between two rows. i've updated my question to reflect this change. do you know how I can compute the cosine similarities on all of the rows with respect to each other on the original matrix?

Comment: @Sal Well, a 65000x65000 matrix has a size of about 31.5GiB, so on a 64GB machine, you should be fine. But you wouldn't be able to store two such matrices. So if python tries to copy the matrix during its construction, you'll be in trouble. Those instances where the computer seems to freeze are probably cases where it's swapping (or paging). Maybe you should just let it run for a while, say overnight... as far as computing the matrix is concerned. But to actually _do_ anything with the matrix, you'll have a hard time.

Answer (score 3):

I would run it in chunks like this

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Change chunk_size to control resource consumption and speed
# Higher chunk_size means more memory/RAM needed but also faster 
chunk_size = 500 
matrix_len = your_matrix.shape[0] # Not sparse numpy.ndarray

def similarity_cosine_by_chunk(start, end):
    if end > matrix_len:
        end = matrix_len
    return cosine_similarity(X=your_matrix[start:end], Y=your_matrix) # scikit-learn function

for chunk_start in xrange(0, matrix_len, chunk_size):
    cosine_similarity_chunk = similarity_cosine_by_chunk(chunk_start, chunk_start+chunk_size)
    # Handle cosine_similarity_chunk  ( Write it to file_timestamp and close the file )
    # Do not open the same file again or you may end up with out of memory after few chunks
```

Comment: For Python3 replace `xrange` by `range`.

Comment: I am confused with this line

cosine_similarity_chunk = similarity_cosine_by_chunk(chunk_start, chunk_start+chunk_size)

why we are overwriting cosine_similarity_chunk variable again and again ?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal . That line is calculating cosine similarity in chunks. With every pass you would have cosine similarity for that chunk only.